# Mockito - verifyNoMoreInteractions- multiple calls with different parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

When calling the same method on mock many times, Mockito seems to be incorrectly interpreting `verifyNoMoreInteractions()`. In example below `someInterface.doSomething(param)` is called multiple times (for each parameter passed):

```
public interface SomeInterface {

    int doSomething(int a);
}
public class SomeService {

    private final SomeInterface someInterface;

    public SomeService(SomeInterface someInterface) {
       this.someInterface = someInterface;
    }

    public int callInterface(int... params) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int param : params) {
            sum += someInterface.doSomething(param); // call for each param
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        SomeInterface myInterfaceMock = mock(SomeInterface.class);
        SomeService myService = new SomeService(myInterfaceMock);

        doReturn(1).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(1);
        doReturn(2).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(2);
        doReturn(3).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(3);

        int sum = myService.callInterface(1, 2, 3);

        assertEquals(1 + 2 + 3, sum);

        verify(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(1);
        verify(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(2);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(myInterfaceMock); // succeeds???

    }

}
```

In above example `verifyNoMoreInteractions(myInterfaceMock)` passes despite `verify(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(3)` not beeing verified. This means that there was still interaction with the mock (namely call to `myInterface.doSomething(3)`). What's the deal?

NOTE: if there was another call say to SomeInterface.someOtherMethod than verifyNoMoreInteractions would signal this, but it seems not to detect above 
situation.

Dependencies for my test use case:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which version of Mockito are you using?

Comment: @JBNizet 3.0.0 - see update on the end of answer

Comment: I managed to reproduce your issue. And curiously, it's caused by `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`. If you remove that line (which isn't useful in this case), the test fails as it should. You should file this as a bug to the Mockito project.

Comment: Just on the side, you can use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this). In order to init any annotations if you use them in this test class. As @JBNizet pointed out the MockitoExtension causes a problem with the verify.

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks for pointing, this lead me into right direction. Indeed removing `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` makes it to work, but the fact that the test does not fail, seems to be expected behaviour (as from Mockito version 3.0.0). This is not a bug. See my answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analysing the docs and taking into consideration usefull comment from (@JBNizet) it seems to be expected behaviour starting from Mockito version 3.0 and JUnit5 (using Mockito extension `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`).

The answer can be found in javadoc of [Mockito Strictness API](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/quality/Strictness.html) where we can read:

> STRICT_STUBS
>
> @Incubating public static final Strictness STRICT_STUBS
>
> Ensures clean tests, reduces test code duplication, improves
>   debuggability. Offers best combination of flexibility and
>   productivity. Highly recommended. Planned as default for Mockito v3.
>
> If you use Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(Object...) you no longer need to
>   explicitly verify stubbed invocations. They are automatically verified
>   for you.

So the stubbed method calls are automatically verified!

What does this mean? If we take example, given in question, it is enough to write test completely omitting calls to `verify(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(x)`. It is enough just to leave call to `verifyNoMoreInteractions(myInterfaceMock)`. Therefore this test also succeeds:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    SomeInterface myInterfaceMock = mock(SomeInterface.class);
    SomeService myService = new SomeService(myInterfaceMock);

    doReturn(1).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(1);
    doReturn(2).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(2);
    doReturn(3).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(3);

    int sum = myService.callInterface(1, 2, 3);

    assertEquals(1 + 2 + 3, sum);

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(myInterfaceMock); // NOTE: no individual verify(myInterfaceMock) calls (!)

}
```

How does Mockito know what was called? Because it analyses stubbings. Mockito figures out which methods should be verified because of this code:

```
    doReturn(1).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(1);
    doReturn(2).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(2);
    doReturn(3).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(3);
```

Mockito, seems to be saying "hey dude, you are expecting `myInterfaceMock` to call `doSomething(1)`, so if you call `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` I will verify if `doSomething(1)` was really called... so individual expectation `verify(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(1)` is redundant.

Automatic verification of individual calls to `verify()` can be enabled if needed by changing the `Strictness` to `WARN` which can be achieved by `@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.WARN)`

Following version of the test fails as initially expected:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.WARN)
class SomeServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        SomeInterface myInterfaceMock = mock(SomeInterface.class);
        SomeService myService = new SomeService(myInterfaceMock);

        doReturn(1).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(1);
        doReturn(2).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(2);
        doReturn(3).when(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(3);

        int sum = myService.callInterface(1, 2, 3);

        assertEquals(1 + 2 + 3, sum);

        verify(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(1);
        verify(myInterfaceMock).doSomething(2);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(myInterfaceMock);

    }

}
```

with message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NoInteractionsWanted: 
No interactions wanted here:
-> at SomeServiceTest.myTest(SomeServiceTest.java:30)
But found this interaction on mock 'someInterface':
-> at SomeService.callInterface(SomeService.java:13)
***
For your reference, here is the list of all invocations ([?] - means unverified).
1. -> at SomeService.callInterface(SomeService.java:13)
2. -> at SomeService.callInterface(SomeService.java:13)
3. [?]-> at SomeService.callInterface(SomeService.java:13)
```

It seems to be up to the designer of the test which Strictess he/she would like to use. New default strictness - STRICT_STUBS for sure reduces the amount of test code written